# pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_cond_wait/signal causing deadlock

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I`m using 2 threads in my program, 1 to print even numbers and the other to print odd numbers sequentially. When I run the below code, the programs blocks after printing 0 and 1. Seems like a deadlock.
But if I move rc=pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex) to above the while statements in both PrintEvenNos() and PrintOddNos(), the output is sequential and complete (as desired). 
Could someone explain why it fails in the first case and what is causing the deadlock?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>

pthread_t tid[2];
unsigned int shared_data = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t even,odd;
unsigned int rc;

void* PrintEvenNos(void*);
void* PrintOddNos(void*);

void main(void)
{
    pthread_create(&tid[0],0,&PrintEvenNos,0);

    pthread_create(&tid[1],0,&PrintOddNos,0);
    sleep(3);

    pthread_join(tid[0],NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[1],NULL);
}

void* PrintEvenNos(void *ptr)
{
    //rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);     /*works when I uncomment here and comment the next mutex_lock */
      while (shared_data <= 5)
     {rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      if(shared_data%2 == 0)
       { printf("t1.....................................Even:%d\n",shared_data);
         shared_data++;
         pthread_cond_signal(&odd);
         rc=pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   }
     else
     {
           pthread_cond_wait(&even, &mutex);
     }
 }
  rc=pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void* PrintOddNos(void* ptr1)
{
// rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);   /*works when I uncomment here and comment the next mutex_lock */
   while (shared_data <= 5)
    {
     rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
     if(shared_data%2 != 0)
        {
        printf("t2.....................................odd:%d\n",shared_data);
            shared_data++;
            pthread_cond_signal(&even);
            rc=pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
        else
            {
               pthread_cond_wait(&odd, &mutex);
        }
    }
 rc=pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Comment: In addition to answers given, you need to initialize your mutex, either statically or with pthread_mutex_init().

Comment: Yes, and also the condition variable. In fact, there already is a default initialization here, because these are global variables. But this is not sufficient in general, you'd need to use `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` and `PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has undefined behavior because your thread that was waiting re-acquired the lock when returning from `pthread_cond_wait` and then calls `pthread_mutex_lock` again on a mutex that it already owns.

Mutexes are meant to be used as you indicate by your comment. This is exactly what `pthread_cond_wait` is made for: it releases the lock on entry and re-acquires it on return.

Also, remove the `pthread_mutex_unlock` from the `if` branch, it is wrong. Generally you should only have one pair of `lock/unlock` calls that mark your critical section.

Answer (score 0):

Move the lock and unlock as you mentioned in your comment. As placed, your program has a race condition and thus undefined behavior. You cannot access data that may be modified by another thread without synchronization to preclude concurrent access.